# How to make FreeRadius identify RADIUS Clients by MAC/Shortname instead of IP?

Tags: radius, freeradius

I use FreeRadius with Postgres SQL.
Is there a way to validate clients (i.e. routers, specifically Mikrotik ones) that uses anything else from Client IP?
The reason why I need that is that clients can have dynamic IP addresses yet I can't go with something as brutal as the following:

```
client 0.0.0.0/0 {
  secret = 12345
  shortname = name
}
```

I'd like to rather use shortname for client identification. For example, if a client with shortname "ABC" is in NAS table of linked PostgresDB, then accept it, else (even if IPs match) reject. Maybe something like that (examples emulate clients.conf but I have to stick with Postgres NAS table)

```
client ABC {
  ipaddr = <ip_address>
  secret = 12345
  #shortname = ABC (as far as I know, it is declared by above, so I may not declare it here)
}
```

Currently, I'm using Static IP's and clients are declared using those in Postgres table NAS.
Thank you in advance for your help.